# How to get Appium to target a real iOS device vs a simulator device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, appium, appium-ios

I am running on `Appium` 1.7.2 and using a `iPhone` 6s on 11.2.5 OS.  I am trying to create a simple test to target a real `iOS` device vs a simulator but each time I run the code `Appium`/`xCode` will open a simulator and use that instead of the real device.

How do I get appium to use the real device.  I have tried supplying the UUID of the device without luck.

Thank you,

Gradle

```
    compile group: 'io.appium', name: 'java-client', version:'6.0.0-BETA2'
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-server', version:'3.8.1'
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-remote-driver', version:'3.8.1'
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version:'3.8.1'
```

Java Code

```
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone 6s");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "11.2");
        //capabilities.setCapability("app", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/appium/TestApp8.4.app.zip");
        capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "Safari");
        capabilities.setCapability("uuid", "26deaa8eb5003b3d56a561ada2fcff2174b00df1");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceOrientation", "portrait");
        capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "safari");
        capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "XCUITest");
```

Comment: Hi, Change uuid to udid in the capability and provide the app capability .ipa file not zip

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run Appium/XCUITest on real device, follow this [guideline](https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md)

The reason why appium takes simulator is that you did not provide `xcodeOrgId` & `xcodeSigningId` capabilities:

```
{
  "xcodeOrgId": "<Team ID in apple dev account>",
  "xcodeSigningId": "iPhone Developer"
}
```

You might face `XCUITest xcodebuild exited with code '65'`, so follow the guide/search on stackoverflow how to fix setup manually.

Good luck!

Comment: I signed up for the apple developer program but I still have xcode open a simulator instead of using my device after adding those capabilities

Comment: Take a look at XCUITest caps: https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver#desired-capabilities and make sure you don't mess it - remove non-required ones and simulator related

Answer (score 1):

To test ios real devices , below capabilities are required

```
  app=${app}    
  version=${version}    
  platform=${platform}    
  deviceName=${deviceName}    
  udid=${udid}    
  platformName=${platformName}    
  newCommandTimeout=2500
  name=${name}    
  automationName=${automationName}    
  xcodeOrgId=${xcodeOrgId}    
  xcodeSigningId=${xcodeSigningId}    
  usePrebuiltWDA=${usePrebuiltWDA}
```

Comment: Not all of them are required ones. Check here https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver#desired-capabilities